# Using python pyscheduler to run dependent tasks

Tags: python, dependencies, scheduler

I am trying to build a utility which could run some processes but before spawning a process, read its dependency from a config. I am trying to use pyscheduler which actually describes what I need [pyScheduler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyScheduler/0.1.0).

```
from pyscheduler.serialScheduler import SerialScheduler
>>> def test_function():
...     print "Called test_function"
... 
>>> scheduler.add_task(task_name = "1", dependencies = ["2","3"], description ="",target_function = test_function ,function_kwargs={"this":1})
>>> scheduler.add_task(task_name = "2", dependencies = ["4"], description ="",target_function = test_function ,function_kwargs={"this":2})
>>> scheduler.add_task(task_name = "3", dependencies = ["5","6"], description ="",target_function = test_function ,function_kwargs={"this":3})
>>> scheduler.add_task(task_name = "4", dependencies = [], description ="",target_function = test_function ,function_kwargs={"this":4})
>>> scheduler.add_task(task_name = "5", dependencies = [], description ="",target_function = test_function ,function_kwargs={"this":5})
>>> scheduler.add_task(task_name = "6", dependencies = [], description ="",target_function = test_function ,function_kwargs={"this":6})
>>> scheduler.run()
[]
```

Why am I getting an empty list? 
What could be a probable approach to give dependency in an external config file and not inside my python script.

Answer (score 0):

the "run" function of the scheduler returns a list of the objects returned by the functions. In your example, the main reason why you get an empty list may is that "test_function" is not returning anything.

You will want to play with the "function_kwargs" parameter if you want to send them to "target_function" i.e.

```
def test_function(function_param):
    print "funtion called with param"%function_param
    return function_param
```

you can change "function_param" by setting "function_kwargs". Ex.

```
..., function_kwargs={"function_param": 2})
```

The function should return "2" and you should see that 2 in the returned list too.

Hope it helps.